# Javascript for loop not working properly in firefox

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I very well might be missing something, or doing this wrong entirely, but this bit of javascript works fine in Chrome and Safari, just not Firefox. The section.id (inside of the if statement) doesn't seem to change but always returns section[0].id regardless if it meets the if statement criteria or not.

```
var localNavigation = {
    showTab: function (anchortags, anchors) {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scroller, i, section, sectionTop, sectionBottom, sectionColor, sectionTextColor, $section;
            for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
                scroller = document.body.scrollTop;
                section = anchors[i];
                $section = $(section);
                sectionColor = $section.css("background-color");
                sectionTextColor = $section.css("color");
                sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
                sectionBottom = section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight;
                if ((scroller > sectionTop) && (scroller < sectionBottom)) {
                    $(anchortags).removeClass("selected").css({
                        "background-color": "transparent",
                        "color": "#f5eeed"
                    });
                    $("#" + section.id + "_tab").addClass("selected").css({
                        "background-color": "" + sectionColor + "",
                        "color": "" + sectionTextColor + ""
                    });
                    console.log(section.id);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    init: function () {
        var anchortags = $("#local ul li a"),
            anchors = $("section");
        localNavigation.showTab(anchortags, anchors);
    }
};
localNavigation.init();
```

Comment: since `anchors` is a jQuery object, you can use `.each()` instead of a for loop

Comment: Don't ask me why but using `scroller = $(window).scrollTop();` instead of `scroller = document.body.scrollTop;` actually did the trick. Thanks for recommending the .each() way of doing it though, Joseph.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you're working on the right file.

Also try an looping using each.

```
anchors.each(function( i, section ){
    var $section = $(section);
    scroller = document.body.scrollTop;
    sectionColor = $section.css("background-color");
    sectionTextColor = $section.css("color");
    sectionTop = $section.offsetTop;
    sectionBottom = $section.offsetTop + $section.offsetHeight;
    if ((scroller > sectionTop) && (scroller < sectionBottom)) {
        console.log($section.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Larry, I actually did go ahead and use the .each() function as you suggested - it didn't quite fix the issue, but it did help me organize things a little better.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using the HTML 5 `<section>` tag.  It has been previously discussed on StackOverflow that many versions of Firefox do not yet support this tag, so have you tried making sure that you're using the most recent version of Firefox?

Failing that, can you try your code with a different tag?

Comment: I was able to get it working (finally) still using the <section> tag in the most current Firefox. I even tried it going back to Firefox 6 and it still works.